# OneDrive doesn't sync new files

Tags: macos, windows-10, sync, onedrive

OneDrive appears to be running on all my machines (2 PC, 1 Mac) as new files added to each will appear in the OneDrive web view.  However, those new files do not ever become accessible on the other machines.  So, each machine has it's own distinct view of my OneDrive folder, with mostly different sets of files (despite the website showing ALL the files).  Synchronization does appear to be happening in some cases though, as there are handful of really old files that do show on all, and if I modify those files the modifications show up on all machines.

Is there some kind of setting I'm missing to tell OneDrive to get new files from the central store too?  Other ideas?

Comment: On Windows, there is a known issue with the OneDrive's Sync Engine becoming corrupt. In my personal experience it was due to the use of directory junctions that messed it up. But with that said I didn't think files would be uploaded if that's the issue here so it's just a thought... Might be worth checking it's nothing to do with [OneDrive Files on Demand](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-onedrive-files-on-demand-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but that's unlikely

Comment: Good idea on the files on demand, but that's not it.

Comment: Ah well, worth a try. I may as well mention that unlinking OneDrive from my account, moving the existing OneDrive folder contents to somewhere safe, then signing in again and allowing all the files to redownload again to an empty folder has been a consistent fix for my issues. Which is annoying, as I have >150GB to download when this occurs, but it really is the only fix I've found. Best of luck sorting it anyway. [Useful link with troubleshooting steps if you're interested](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/onedrive-sync-problems-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "choose folders" option somehow did not include all folders.  Files not in a folder were selected on all machines, but a different combination of folders was selected on each.  Looks like folders created locally were selected, but others were not coming in.  Sync all files and folders was mysteriously off, so turned it on and they're all synching up fine now!